# Finitely co/continuous monad induced by an operad

Tags: ct.category-theory, operads

It is well known that any operad on a nice monoidal category [induces a monad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad#the_monad_attached_to_an_operad).

I was wondering which conditions can be imposed on the operad $T$ (say, in a monoidal closed $\cal V$) so that the induced monad $\hat T$ on $\cal V$ commutes with finite co/limits.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Preservation of terminal objects seems like a tall order, at least when the monoidal category is cartesian.  If the operad is called $P$ then this would give $\sum_n P_n = \hat{T}(1) = 1$.  But maybe you're not interested in the cartesian case.  If not, could you give a hint as to what kind of example you are interested in?

Comment: I hoped in your answer! I'm not interested in some particular example: I agree that in the cartesian case the condition is rather strong and unnatural: I'm basically interested in cases where the monoidal structure arises as a "tensor between algebras" (modules over a ring? chain complexes?); I've been deliberately vague, but a more precise question should be: does any "famous" operad induce a cocontinuous monad?

Comment: I would expect this to almost never happen. A decategorified version of your question would be: which power series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n x^n}{n!}$ commute with sums, $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, which I think only happens (with characteristic 0 coefficients) if $a_n = 0$ for $n \neq 1$. This suggests that maybe you can find mild hypothesis on $\mathcal{V}$ so that $\hat{T}$ commutes with coproducts only if the operad is concentrated in degree 1.

Comment: Also, you said "operad" but the question is only about the underlying symmetric sequence because you are interested in a property of just the functor part of the monad.

Comment: Still commenting rather than answering because I haven't got anything nontrivial to say... but if you view a monoid $M$ as an operad (with no operations of arity $\neq 1$) then the resulting monad is $M \otimes -$, which preserves colimits if your monoidal category is closed.  But that's all I can think of.

Comment: @TomLeinster: that's precisely where I started from :)

Comment: Another little observation: if $T$ is a finitary monad on Set (such as the one induced by an operad) and the forgetful functor from $T$-algebras to Set preserves colimits, then $T$ is of the form $M \times -$ for some monoid $M$.  That doesn't quite fit your situation, but begins to suggest that there aren't any nontrivial examples.  (It's Lemma 1.2 of Peter Johnstone's paper "When is a variety a topos?")